# Is it possible to recover a simplicial complex from its 1-skeleton via its barycentric subdivision?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex, barycentric-coordinates

As in the title, suppose I start with a simplicial complex, perform a barycentric subdivision once, compute its 1-skeleton, then hand it to you, and you are told about this procedure. Can you recover the simplicial complex I started with upto homotopy?

Comment: I don’t know if asking up to homotopy equivalence is the correct thing here since this process doesn’t even respect homotopy equivalence.

Comment: You should be able to recover it even up to isomorphism according to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5245.pdf, Theorem 2.2. Reconstruction only up to homeomorphism is trivial - you just take the clique complex of your graph.